# A Node.js error when trying to escape data before insert to MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have some code to insert a data to mysql table. But before I run a query I escape values, like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const R = require('ramda');

class Repository {
  constructor(connection) {
    this.connection = connection;
    this.escapeList = R.map(this.connection.escape);
  }

  insertQuery(table, obj) {
    return `INSERT INTO ${table} (${Object.keys(obj).join(',')})
     VALUES (${this.escapeList(Object.values(obj))});`
   };

   updateProfile(profile) {
     return this.insertQuery('degree', { userId: 1, university: 'msu', degree: 'bs', field: 'cs', graduation: 2017 });
   }
```

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'timezone' of undefined
```

And the problem is right here:

```
this.escapeList = R.map(this.connection.escape);
```

Because if I change this line to `this.escapeList = R.map(x => this.connection.escape(x));` everything is fine. But now it's not so elegant like first one.

So why it's happening and ho fix that?

Comment: Can you narrow it down to the particular value that's throwing the error?

Comment: integer or string throwing the error

Comment: That's not a particular value. I mean start removing columns until you only have one left and that one causes an error. Cut this problem down to size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `this.connection.escape` removes the context (the meaning of `this`) from the method call. You have to explicitly bind that context if you want to pass the method around as a reference:

```
R.map(this.connection.escape.bind(this.connection))
```

Which isn't really very elegant either.

You can use this instead:

```
R.map(mysql.escape)
```

Or, alternatively, let `mysql` format and escape the query itself:

```
insertQuery(table, obj) {
  return mysql.format('INSERT INTO ?? SET ?', [ table, obj ]);
}
```

Or in case you really want to use `INSERT ... VALUES`:

```
insertQuery(table, obj) {
  return mysql.format('INSERT INTO ?? (?) VALUES (?)', [ table, Object.keys(obj), Object.values(obj) ]);
}
```